# styling textview with json parsing

Tags: php, android, json, parsing, textview

I got a piece of code that's parsing my db values to my android activity but I want it to style it different then it is now.

This is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.leesverslag);
    /* Werkt altijd */
    // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources  
    // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.
    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());  
    rootLayout.addView(txt);  
    setContentView(rootLayout);
    /* Werkt altijd */
    // Set the text and call the connect function.  
    //txt.setText("Connecting..."); 
    //call the method to run the data retrieval
    txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121)); 
}
```

I think it's coming cause I say, LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContect());

But I don't know how to fix this so it will work with my own layout.

The new layout is showing me.

http://www.wvvzondag2.nl/android/leesverslag.php

```
{"introtext": "<p>my custom value text for a android application<\/p>"}
```

And I would like to see
my custom value text for a android application

This is my php code.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$user = '***';  
$pswd = '***';  
$db = '***';  
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $pswd);  
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);  
$sql =  mysql_query("SELECT jos_content.introtext FROM jos_content, jos_categories WHERE jos_categories.id = '80' AND jos_content.state = '1' AND jos_categories.id = jos_content.catid AND jos_content.title = '".$_REQUEST['titel']."'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($output));
mysql_close;
?>
```

Can somebody please help me with what to do to get it working with my own layout?

Kind regards,
Patrick